# Markdown and HTML editor app?

Tags: html, note-taking, markdown

Is there a note-taking app that allows me to write in Markdown and then continue editing in HTML and vice-versa? I mean it has the ability to convert HTML to Markdown as well?

Some less-formatted notes are easier to write in Markdown, however I often prefer to edit in WYSIWYG.

Preferably the app works for iOS, but OS X is also accepted (those are the two platforms that I use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an iOS app called [Go Edit](http://basilsalad.com/ios/go-edit/) that you can use to edit markdown files and convert them to HTML or vise-versa.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the universal document converter Pandoc in addition with some editor. It does convert from Markdown to HTML and vice versa. [Some plugins exists](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Pandoc-Extras#editors) which integrate Pandoc's conversion functionality into text editors. Some of them are available for texts editors which run on OS X. In addition, to that, you may want to use a [WYSIWYG HTML Editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTML_editors#WYSIWYG_editors) in order to edit your HTML source. I do not know any with Pandoc integration, though.

If you require using a WYSIWYG HTML Editor it is not very satisfying as you need to use two editors in total. But maybe this can be a starting point.